# Switching branch on Xcode 9

Tags: xcode, git, macos, version-control, xcode9-beta

I am having trouble finding the menu item to switch branch using Xcode 9. The working copies menu seems to have disappeared. Any ideas?

**Xcode 9**

[image]

**Xcode 8**

[image]

Comment: There's a new source control navigator button beside the project navigator button that might be intended for some use but all it tells me is "Loading...".

Comment: You could review [Apple Session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/fall2017/204/)...

Answer (score 180, accepted):

- Press <kbd>⌘2</kbd> to open the new Source Control Navigator.
- Right-click on the `master` icon.

[image]

To switch to a different branch

- Right-click on a non-current branch
- Choose `Checkout...`
- Press <kbd>↩</kbd> or click on the `Checkout` button.

[image]

Comment: Yes, but you see there is no "Switch to Branch…" in that contextual menu, as there was in earlier Xcodes.  In Xcode 9, you use "Checkout…" (which will be enabled when you select any non-current branch).  I like this, because the terminology now matches the git command line command you would use.

Comment: It takes time to find the branch from Remotes. Do you know the way to search remotes brand with Name?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know a way.

Comment: In the repo I'm working in there are yellow folders within the branch names. This dev team has yellow folders with app version numbers for the folder names then branches inside those folders. How did they do that? https://i.imgur.com/zKoWxD6.png

Answer (score 17):

Expose the left side window (Navigator) in your Xcode by selecting this option (you will see this on the top right side of your Xcode window):

[image: Enabling the Navigator]

Now select the second tab:

[image: Selecting the Source control tab]

Right click on the branch you are intending to checkout and hit the checkout button from menu:
[image: Checking out the branch]

Answer (score 16):

It seems that Apple has moved **Source Controls** feature like `change branch`, `version history` to separate tab in **Navigator area** for Xcode 9.x

Below are step to perform branch switch :

1. Open the `Navigator area` (if it is hidden) by pressing left pane window present on top right of Xcode or use shortcut **cmd + 2**

[image: step1]

2. In `Source control navigator` you can see `Branches`, `Tag` present for your project.

[image: Step2]

3. Now, if you want to switch branch then *select the branch to switch* and *right click* on it.
4. Select *Checkout*. This will prompt an alert `Do you want to check out “<branch name>”?`  Select `Checkout`.

[image: Step3-4]

5. Now this will switch your branch to selected one after sometime.

*Note: In order to switch between branches you need to commit or discard changes done in project.*

[image: Step5]

[image: Step6]

6. You can even see **Log history** by selecting branch. Commit history can be viewed based on last 24 hours, last 7 days and last 30 days.

[image: Step 6]

[image: Step 7]

Answer (score 3):

1) Press show navigator button (top right corner of Xcode):

[image]

2) Show the project navigator, expand `Remotes` folder:
[image]

3) Expand the origin folder, right click the branch you want to use, and click `Checkout...`. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below link for the clear explanation of each and every functionality like, Commit, pull, push, etc.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/153084/use-git-source-control-xcode-9