# How to switch to remote git branch in Xcode9?

Tags: ios, xcode, git, version-control, git-branch

I want to switch to remote branch from my application in Xcode 9, I have tried with check-out option in Xcode the remote branch from Xcode. Does it the right way to do that, Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. Ram is asking how to do it *in* xcode9. We used to have a quick "Switch Branch" menu option. It seems to be gone now. That is what (i think) he is seeking. I have the same question.

Comment: For completeness, the correct answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44396681/switching-branch-on-xcode-9